# How to use throughput controller for much samplers in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

if the number of samplers is very high, nearly **100**, how to use throughput controller in jmeter?
i want all samplers to be sent with equal number by jmeter.

my test configuration:
ultimate thread group : 50 threads, 10 minutes, ramp up 10s, ramp down 10s

sampler1 ,

sampler2 ,

...

sampler100.

throughput controller is not used.

when the test is executed the total request numbers will be like this:

sampler1 : 150 ,

sampler2 : 145 ,

sampler50 : 5 ,

sampler100 : 0

this is not the case that i want.
if i use the throughput controller (all the samplers are in the throughput controller), the result will not change satisfactory.
have any idea for the solution?

Comment: It looks like your test stopped even before the last sampler `sampler100` is reached. If you want to ensure all requests are executed with an equal number, set the Thread iteration limit to the number you want to and increase the hold-rate time to a higher value in the Concurrency thread group. Else you may use the normal thread group with a fixed loop count.

Answer (score 0):

[Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) doesn't guarantee that its children will be executed specified amount of times (or at least once), it can only limit the number of its children execution to the defined value.

If you have 100 samplers and 10 minutes + 20 seconds test duration if average response time exceeds 6 seconds - not all samplers will be executed

If you want all the 100 samplers to be executed at least once within the bounds of 10 minutes time frame you need to limit the time JMeter waits for the response to something below 6 seconds, i.e. to 5 seconds.

In case of [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler the timeout setting can be found at "Advanced" tab

[image]

or better use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults), in this case you won't have to set the timeout 100 times.

Also make sure that "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" is set to `Continue`

[image]

as having 150 occurrences of execution of 1st sampler most probably means that there is an error somewhere and the user is restarted so it executes samplers from the beginning once again